# docker-compose mysql health check inline complex command

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-healthcheck

docker-compose mysql health check inline complex command:

```
serivces:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./init-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD-SHELL
        - if [[ -z "$(ls -A /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d)" ]]; then
              mysql -u root -p123456 -e 'select 0'
          else
              mysql -u root -p123456 --database my_db -e 'show tables' | [ $(wc -l) -gt 100 ]
          fi
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 50
```

Mysql not healthy.

It works without if/else in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

With CMD-SHELL test is run as `sh -c '<test>'`, this causes errors if test command contains quotes.

**Either** escape the quotes in your command to run successfully with `sh -c`

**Or** put the complex command in a script file, mount the script file into container volumes and change health check command accordingly

```
volumes:
  - ./hc.sh:/healthcheck.sh
healthcheck:
  test:
    - CMD-SHELL
    - /healthcheck.sh
```

Comment: inline version: tried single (\")and double escape (\\"), not working.

Comment: I suggest going the script route as escapes etc. reduce maintainability.